# Custom text input using Expo Modules API

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to create custom text input component using this guide https://docs.expo.dev/modules/native-view-tutorial/ however I found that to provide ability to use styling and all another basic things from React Native TextInput I should extend it somehow.

My current implementation relay on UITextField. How can I extend RN TextInput instead of UITextField?

```swift
class InputView: ExpoView, UITextFieldDelegate {
    var value: String? {
        didSet {
            updateTextField()
        }
    }

    var textField = UITextField()

    required init(appContext: AppContext? = nil) {
        super.init(appContext: appContext)
        self.addSubview(textField)
        clipsToBounds = true
        addSubview(textField)
        textField.delegate = self
     }
     
     // Another implementation

}
```